# Akka HTTP asynchronous directives

Tags: scala, promise, akka-http

I would  like to implement an asynchronous session token control in an Akka HTTP-based web server before a series of sensible routes would be processed.

In my idea of implementation, I would have a method that performs the authentication that would look like the following:

```
def performAuthentication(sessionToken: String): Future[Result]
```

where `Result` would be a case class containing the authentication result. In order to perform the authentication, I would like to write a Directive that could be placed before the sensible routes, that would look like the following:

```
def authenticate: Directive1[SessionToken] = optionalHeaderValueByName("session-token").flatMap {
    case Some(sessionToken) if (...) => provide(SessionToken(sessionToken))
    case _ => complete(StatusCodes.Unauthorized)
}
```

with `SessionResult` a case class wrapping the sessionToken that I would provide to the subsequents routes. In place of the suspension points, I'm forced to await for the `Promise` result, because if I implement the `onComplete ... Success ... Failure` pattern, like in the following:

```
onComplete(this.performAuthentication(sessionToken)) {
    case Success(value) if (value.isAuthenticated) => provide(SessionToken(sessionToken))
    case Failure(ex) => failWith(ex)
    case _ => complete(StatusCodes.Unauthorized)
}
```

the compiler warns me that `provide` and `complete` returns two different types... and it's right.

My question is: is there a way to write an asynchronous `Directive` that could also provide some value, that could be placed in the normal route definition?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could create a Directive like this

```
type Token = String
def checkRequest(f: HttpRequest => Future[Token])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Directive1[Token] =
  Directive { inner => ctx =>
    val futureToken = f(ctx.request)
    futureToken.flatMap(tkn => inner(Tuple1(tkn))(ctx))
  }
```

You can create this directive by giving it a function that does the authentication. If you want to handle rejections as well `Token` could be an `Either[ErrorAuth, Token]`